# Почему в React + Mobx не работает ручное обновление страницы?

Tags: reactjs, webpack4, webpack-dev-server, mobx

Запустил на webpack-dev-server приложение.
Все работает кроме ручного обновления страницы.
Пишет : Cannot GET /articles

Answer (score 1):

добавьте в свой `webpack.config.js`

```
devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
}
```

Более подробно о ключе `historyApiFallback` [тут](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverhistoryapifallback)

Comment: Спасибо, заработало

Comment: @bank45 если не сложно, отметьте ответ галочкой:)